# How to make scrolling list-group column same height as adjacent column?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4 mark-up, I have a left-hand column which contains a `.list-group`, which, dynamically generated, could contain dozens of `.list-group-item`s.

On its right, I have a column containing a `.row` which itself contains numerous cards, all inside columns. There may be hundreds of these...

[image]

```
<h3 class="text-secondary pb-3">Header</h3>

<div class="row">

   <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 d-none d-sm-block" style="max-height: 7000px; overflow-y: scroll;">
     <div class="list-group list-unstyled">
       <a href="http://www.example.com/link" alt="View all post filed under example" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
         <span><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=example.com" class="mr-2">Example link</span>
         <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">26</span>
       </a>
       <a href="http://www.example.com/link" alt="View all post filed under example" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
         <span><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=example.com" class="mr-2">Example link</span>
         <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">26</span>
       </a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-9>
       <div class="row">
        Lots of cards throughout this row, inside .col-lg-4 cards.
       </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

Depending on the amount of content on the right, the left-hand `.list-group` may come up far longer than the volume on the right. In such a case, I want the displayed height of the `.list-group` to be limited and for the `.list-group` to be independently scrollable.

I have managed to implement that by applying the CSS rule `overflow-y: scroll;` to the column containing it, which feels great...

[image]

The thing is, I can only manage it by manually setting the height of the column at, eg. `max-height:7000px;`.

The trouble with this is, depending on the volume of content on the right, it risks shortening the viewable `.list-group`. In this example, the bottom of the left-hand `.list-group` column should stretch to the bottom of the adjacent right-hand content, whilst also retaining independent scrolling...

[image]

How can I ensure that, where the left-hand column / the `.list-group`is physically longer than the content on its right, has its viewable height cut short to match the height of the stuff on the right?

This should retain `overflow-y: scroll;` so that, if the list is still longer than what is on the right, it can scroll vertically.

Solution would ideally use Bootstrap 4 styles and not resort to writing custom CSS rules.

Comment: you can use `100vh` or google `calc() css function`

Comment: Applied to what? Applied as `.100vh` to the `.list-group`, it only elongates the column to be its own maximum. It should stop at the depth of the adjacent column. I guess it's not a class. Instead, `style="height: 100vh"` just makes the list column the height of the viewpoint. That isn't what I need either.

Answer (score 0):

Since the overflow scroll needs a fixed `height`, you can't use `auto`. You need to change the height of scroll area with jquery using the height of cards area with base.

If the content is generate dinamically, you need set a timeout before equal the heights.

Here is a example using jquery. In the example, I get the height of cards area and set it to height of list group area.

Html

```
<h3 class="text-secondary pb-3">Header</h3>

<div class="row">

   // Add a class to the list group area and set height instead max-height
   <div class="list-group-area col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 d-none d-sm-block" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;">
     <div class="list-group list-unstyled">
       <a href="http://www.example.com/link" alt="View all post filed under example" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
         <span><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=example.com" class="mr-2">Example link</span>
         <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">26</span>
       </a>
       <a href="http://www.example.com/link" alt="View all post filed under example" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
         <span><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=example.com" class="mr-2">Example link</span>
         <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">26</span>
       </a>
     </div>
   </div>

   // Add a class to the card area
   <div class="cards-area col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
       <div class="row">
        Lots of cards throughout this row, inside .col-lg-4 cards.
       </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Delay
      setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.list-group-area').height($('.cards-area').height());
      }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Yes, it works, technically. Though the rendering delay of the left-hand column is noticeable, and I can't help but have hoped there were more of a Bootstrap-centric way to do it.

Comment: The delay seems more apparent because the column has to step up from a starter of `height: 300px` as suggested to whatever it needs to be  (which leaves a lot of grey space needing to be filled). If I switch the starting height style to `height: 100vh`, the user sees no space except if they scroll the viewport. The trouble with that, though, is that there may legitimately be pairing of `.list-group` and the content area where neither is as high as the viewport. In this scenario, setting `height: 100vh` leaves tons of grey vertical space. unfilled.

Comment: Yep, I set the 300px just for start with a small size and grow using the size of cards area. There is no other way to do that without jquery when the height of elements are not fixed. Maybe you can make the height of cards side fixe, using the size of each card plus the margin/padding, but if you have less than the number of cards for the height the white space is appears. I can't see other way to do that.

Comment: You can adjust the delay for you case, `1000` it is just for the example.

Comment: I tested with as low as 100.

Comment: Is a starting `style=height:` value required at all? If the column were just allowed to render at its actual physical size and then let the JQuery change its size, perceptible delays or changes may be reduced, since the change occurs off-canvas (?). That said, when I test omitting it, the JQuery doesn't seem to kick in, the column doesn't get shortened.

Comment: @RobertAndrews it is no required manually set the height of list group in html. You need to set just the `overflow-y` and when the page is ready and timeout is over, the height will be set. I made an example in JSfiddle, in this example I use jquery animate to smooth the resize: http://jsfiddle.net/cxL5jzg4/

Comment: Maybe your problem is in timeout, if the all elements in cards area are not loaded the resize is not apply because the list group is bigger than cards area.

Comment: Definitely only works IF a height is applied to list-group-area.

Comment: The list group needs to receive the same height of cards area, just that. In Jsfiddle example it works. If it is not working in your case, update your post with the code to reproduce the same thing you doing, use jsfiddle if is needed. Only with your code we can test and help you better.